# HHow to add an external library to an Android Studio project?

Tags: android

How to add this library (https://github.com/swapnil1104/CurveGraphView) to Android Studio project? I've tried so many things and still can't figure it out...

I just started to learn, so if you can in more detail. I tried to import through the build.gradle file, well, I constantly see an error [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjWpB.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are tru to use this gradle link to implementation in gradle file.

implementation 'com.github.swapnil1104:CurveGraphView:2.1'